# Using induction to prove a formula for $\sin x+\sin 3x+\dots+\sin (2n-1)x$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, summation, proof-writing, induction

I'm working from the text "Intro To Real Analysis" by William Trench. Here is what I have thus far.

I will prove using Mathematical Induction that $\sin x+\sin 3x+...+\sin (2n-1)x=\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x}, $ where $n\ge 1.$ Consider the case where $n=1$, which will serve as our base case. Clearly, for $n=1$ it is true that $$\sin x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2\sin x}$$ since $\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$ is an identity. Next, we assume that $\sin x+\sin 3x+...+\sin (2n-1)x=\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x} $ is true for $n$ and then using Mathematical Induction, we verify the $n+1$ case, that is to say, we observe that $$\frac{1-\cos 2(n+1)x}{2\sin x} = \frac{1 - \cos(2nx+2x)}{2\sin x}$$ $$ = \frac{1-\cos(2nx)\cos(2x)-\sin(2nx)\sin(2x)}{2\sin x}$$ $$ =???.$$

I'm not sure where I can go from here. I realize I want to transform the last line into $\sin x+\sin 3x+...+\sin (2n)x$, but can't see how I can get there.

Any helpful hints would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Suppose you may substitute $\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x}$ for the sum of sines of $x$ through $(2n-1)x$, thus getting an equality to prove: $$\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x} + \sin(2n+1)x = \frac{1-\cos 2(n+1)x}{2\sin x}$$

Comment: Oh! So I should go about it the opposite way than I initially tried?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can continue like this (just the second term of the numerator):
$$\cos 2(n+1)x = \cos(2nx+2x) =\cos 2nx\cos 2x - \sin 2nx \sin 2x$$
$$=\cos 2nx(\cos^2x-\sin^2x) - \sin 2nx \sin 2x$$
$$=\cos 2nx(1-2\sin^2x) - 2\sin 2nx \sin x\cos x$$
$$=\cos 2nx - 2\cos 2nx\sin^2x - 2\sin 2nx \sin x\cos x$$
$$=\cos 2nx - (\cos 2nx\sin x + \sin 2nx \cos x)2\sin x$$
$$=\cos 2nx - \sin(2nx+x)2\sin x = \cos 2nx - \sin 2(n+1)x \cdot 2\sin x$$
which implies:
$$\frac{1-\cos 2(n+1)x}{2\sin x}
=\frac{1-\cos 2nx + \sin 2(n+1)x \cdot 2\sin x}{2\sin x}$$
$$=\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x} + \sin 2(n+1)x.$$

Comment: However, the 'proof' above is based on a false assumption, so we prove an 'identity' which is false...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\cos 2nx\cos 2n+\sin 2nx\sin 2x=\cos(2nx-2x)=\cos\left(2x(n-1)\right)$$

Edited:

$$\sin x+\sin 3x\ldots+\sin((2n-1)x+\sin((2n+1)x\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hypothesis}}=$$

$$=\frac{1-\cos2nx}{2\sin x}+\sin((2n+1)x$$

Observe that the added term for $\;n+1\;$ is $\;\sin((2n+1)x\;$ , **not** $\;\sin 2nx\;$ !

Now, you want the last line above to equal

$$\frac{1-\cos2nx}{2\sin x}+\sin((2n+1)x)=\frac{\cos((2n+2)x)}{2\sin x}\iff$$

$$\frac{\cos((2n+2)x)+\cos2nx-1}{2\sin x}=\sin((2n+1)x)\iff$$

$$\cos 2nx\cos2x-\sin2nx\sin2x+\cos2n x=2\sin x\sin((2n+1)x)$$

Take it from here now.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is useful. Could you elaborate just a tad more without completely giving away the solution? Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you using your double sided arrows as an \textbf{iff} abbreviation or to say implies?

Comment: It's double implication, of course.

Comment: Haha, sorry for asking for clarification, it's just that I've seen too many different meanings represented by the double arrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The induction hypothesis is
$$
\sin x+\sin 3x+\dots+\sin (2n-1)x=\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x}
$$
so
$$
\sin x+\sin 3x+\dots+\sin (2n-1)x+\sin(2n+1)x=
\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2\sin x}+\sin(2n+1)x
$$
and the right hand side can be written as
$$
\frac{1-\cos2nx+2\sin(2n+1)x\sin x}{2\sin x}
$$
so we are bound to prove that
$$
1-\cos2nx+2\sin(2n+1)x\sin x=1-\cos2(n+1)x
$$
or
$$
\cos2(n+1)x-\cos2nx=-2\sin(2n+1)x\sin x
$$
By prostapheresis,
$$
\cos\alpha-\cos\beta=-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
and indeed,
$$
\frac{2(n+1)x+2nx}{2}=(2n+1)x,\qquad
\frac{2(n+1)x-2nx}{2}=x.
$$

Without knowing prostapheresis, you can write
$$
2(n+1)x=(2n+1)x+x
$$
and
$$
2nx=(2n+1)x-x
$$
and apply the addition and subtraction formulas for the cosine.

Comment: The only identities I can use are $\cos(A+B)$ and $\cos(A-B)$.

Comment: Well, prostapheresis follows from considering $\cos(A+B)-\cos(A-B)$.